# How can I fix setOnItemClickListener for 2 gridviews that make the wrong result?

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

this is my code

```
// 1st gridview 
        prepareList1();
        mAdapter = new GridView_Adapter(this,listAccName, listAccIcon);
        gridView1 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1;
        gridView1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        gridView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,"position = " + position + ":"+ mAdapter.getItem(position) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    // 2nd gridview
    prepareList2();
        mAdapter = new GridView_Adapter(this,listCatName, listCatIcon);
        gridView2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview2);
        gridView2.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        gridView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(Main.this,"position = " + position + ":"+ mAdapter.getItem(position) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

but when I click on the first gridview item, it shows the second gridview variable on Toast. I try making difference variable name, but the result is the same.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   GridView_Adapter  mAdapter1 = new GridView_Adapter(this,listCatName, listCatIcon);
            gridView2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview2);
            gridView2.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
```

Just change this three lines